# Connecting to GCP cloudsql using pgadmin

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am connecting to GCP cloudsql instance using pgadmin, I have set up my ip in the authorized networks under public ips in GCP connection settings. Everytime my wifi restarts i end up having a new ip, updating the new ip in the console is tiresome, expecting a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#what_the_provides) is the proper tool how to connect to Cloud SQL. It creates a local proxy, so you basically connect to localhost.